# How to change font family in Jetpack Compose programmatically?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I'm building an Android app and I wanted to add an option in the settings for the user to choose either he wants to use The app custom font family or just use the dafault system font family and maybe also options for other fonts. Is there an option in compose to do this?

Comment: Start with [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes)

Answer (score 4):

For Material3 (Material Design 3):

> Note: Unlike the M2 Typography class, the M3 Typography class doesn’t
> currently include a `defaultFontFamily` parameter. You’ll need to use
> the `fontFamily` parameter in each of the individual TextStyles instead.
> ([Source](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/designsystems/material3#typography))

So, here is an example of setting the default font-family in M3:

```kotlin
// Type.kt

import androidx.compose.material3.Typography
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.Font
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import com.example.exampleapp.R

// Declare the font families
object AppFont {
    val TitilliumWeb = FontFamily(
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_regular),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_italic, style = FontStyle.Italic),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_medium, FontWeight.Medium),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_medium_italic, FontWeight.Medium, style = FontStyle.Italic),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_bold, FontWeight.Bold),
        Font(R.font.titillium_web_bold_italic, FontWeight.Bold, style = FontStyle.Italic)
    )
}

private val defaultTypography = Typography()
val Typography = Typography(
    displayLarge = defaultTypography.displayLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    displayMedium = defaultTypography.displayMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    displaySmall = defaultTypography.displaySmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    headlineLarge = defaultTypography.headlineLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    headlineMedium = defaultTypography.headlineMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    headlineSmall = defaultTypography.headlineSmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    titleLarge = defaultTypography.titleLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    titleMedium = defaultTypography.titleMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    titleSmall = defaultTypography.titleSmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    bodyLarge = defaultTypography.bodyLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    bodyMedium = defaultTypography.bodyMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    bodySmall = defaultTypography.bodySmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),

    labelLarge = defaultTypography.labelLarge.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    labelMedium = defaultTypography.labelMedium.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb),
    labelSmall = defaultTypography.labelSmall.copy(fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb)
)
```

```kotlin
// Theme.kt

import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable

@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Example for an individual component:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import com.example.exampleapp.theme.AppFont

@Composable
fun ExampleScreen() {
    Text(
        text = "Hello World!", 
        fontFamily = AppFont.TitilliumWeb
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by using the `defaultFontFamily` parameter, adding an extra parameter to `MyAppTheme` Composable and passing the typography object to the `MaterialTheme()` constructor instead of the default one as you can see the code below :

```kotlin
fun getTypography(fontFamily: FontFamily) = Typography(
    defaultFontFamily = fontFamily
)
```

In `Theme.kt` :

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyAppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Added fontFamily param
    fontFamily: FontFamily = Rubik,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit) {

    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    val typography = getTypography(fontFamily)

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using androidx.compose.material3.Typography, there would be 2 approaches:
First one is to copy each style and change the font family.

```
fun createTypography(parent: Typography, fontFamily: FontFamily): Typography{
return Typography(
    parent.displayLarge.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.displayMedium.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.displaySmall.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.headlineLarge.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.headlineMedium.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.headlineSmall.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.titleLarge.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.titleMedium.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.titleSmall.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.bodyLarge.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.bodyMedium.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.bodySmall.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.labelLarge.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.labelMedium.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily),
    parent.labelSmall.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily)
    )    
}
```

the other way is to use reflection:

```kotlin
fun createTypographyReflection(parent: Typography, fontFamily: FontFamily): Typography{
val result = Typography()
Typography::class.java.declaredFields.filter { it.type == TextStyle::class.java }.forEach { field ->
    field.isAccessible = true
    val textStyle = field.get(parent) as TextStyle
    val modifiedTextStyle = textStyle.copy(fontFamily = fontFamily)
    field.set(result, modifiedTextStyle)
}
return result
}
```